# Retrieve AD attributes based off of username provided

Tags: vbscript

I have a function (below) that can provide the AD attributes I need (First Name and Last Name) with the currently logged in user but what I want is for a user to enter a username, pass it to this function, and look up the First and Last name based off of that passed username.

```
Function ADFullName(strName)

    Dim objSysInfo, objUser, strRet
    Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")

    ' Currently logged in User
    Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objSysInfo.UserName)

    strRet = msgbox("If this is your full name, click yes to proceed, otherwise click NO and re-enter your new username:" & vbclf & vbclf & objUser.FirstName & " " & objUser.LastName, vbYesNo, "Confirm Name")

    If strRet = vbYes Then
        Msgbox "You answered yes."
    Else
        Msgbox "You answered no."
    End If

End Function
```